# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in loss.backward in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to implement a Deep Q network (DQN) using a graph convolution network (GCN) using the dynamic graph library (DGL). The base code is taken from this [repository](https://github.com/louisv123/COLGE/blob/master/agent.py). However, after I calculate the loss between the policy network and target network and run `loss.backward()`, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. I have printed the loss value and it is not `None`.

I ran the original code from the repository and it is running perfectly. I have also implemented the GCN code in DGL and it seems to run. I have also visualized the graph using the `torchviz`, but I am unable to find why it is giving an error.

The code snippet is given below:

```py
target = reward_tens + self.gamma * torch.max(self.model_target(observation_tens, self.G) + observation_tens * (-1e5), dim=1)[0]

current_q_values= self.model(last_observation_tens, self.G)
next_q_values=current_q_values.clone()
current_q_values[range(self.minibatch_length),action_tens,:] = target

L=self.criterion(current_q_values,next_q_values)
print('loss:',L.item())
self.optimizer.zero_grad()
L.backward(retain_graph=True)

self.optimizer.step()
```

> loss: 1461729.125

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cd5e862dd609> in <module>()
     62 
     63 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 64     main()

7 frames
<ipython-input-17-cd5e862dd609> in main()
     55         print("Running a single instance simulation...")
     56         my_runner = Runner(env_class, agent_class, args.verbose)
---> 57         final_reward = my_runner.loop(graph_dic,args.ngames,args.epoch, args.niter)
     58         print("Obtained a final reward of {}".format(final_reward))
     59         agent_class.save_model()

<ipython-input-14-45cfc883a37b> in loop(self, graphs, games, nbr_epoch, max_iter)
     45                         # if self.verbose:
     46                         #   print("Simulation step {}:".format(i))
---> 47                         (obs, act, rew, done) = self.step()
     48                         action_list.append(act)
     49 

<ipython-input-14-45cfc883a37b> in step(self)
     16         #reward = torch.tensor([reward], device=device)
     17 
---> 18         self.agent.reward(observation, action, reward,done)
     19 
     20         return (observation, action, reward, done)

<ipython-input-16-76d612e8663c> in reward(self, observation, action, reward, done)
    129               print('loss:',L.item())
    130               self.optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 131               L.backward(retain_graph=True)
    132               self.optimizer.step()
    133 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    148                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    149         """
--> 150         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    151 
    152     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     97     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     98         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 99         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    100 
    101 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/function.py in apply(self, *args)
     75 
     76     def apply(self, *args):
---> 77         return self._forward_cls.backward(self, *args)
     78 
     79 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dgl/backend/pytorch/tensor.py in backward(ctx, grad_out)
    394     def backward(ctx, grad_out):
    395         reducer, graph, target, in_map, out_map, in_data_nd, out_data_nd, degs \
--> 396             = ctx.backward_cache
    397         ctx.backward_cache = None
    398         grad_in = None

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you include more of the stack trace?

Comment: @MihailBurduja: I have added the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Issue solved by building from source on master branch.**
*Check out this [issue](https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/issues/1046) for details.*

So I had the same issue, when generating a toy dataset of random graphs in DGL. For each graph I computed the corresponding targets using `G.update_all(fn.copy_e(‘msg’),fn.sum(‘msg’,’c’))` and `target=dgl.sum_nodes(G,’c’)`. When I called `loss.backward()` I got the same error as you do.

I fixed this by adding `torch.no_grad()` around the creation of my `DataLoader` object, so `loss.backward()` does not call the `backward()` functions inside `target`, where `ctx.backward_cache = None`, when the `forward()` of the `CopyReduce()` class in [dgl/tensor.py](https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/blob/master/python/dgl/backend/pytorch/tensor.py#L364) has not been called prior to it.

I am not sure my fix applies directly to your problem, but you should check if you have a backward pass without a forward pass prior to this or the tensors in your loss-function are referring to the same computations in the graph and thereby calling `backward()` twice.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However this did not solve the problem

Comment: I see. So this seems like a issue inherent to DGL's autograd functions, where they explicitly set `ctx.backward_cache = None` in each backward pass, even when `retain_graph=True`. A naive quick fix could be to outcomment line 397 in `dgl/backend/pytorch/tensor.py`. I posted this issue at [dgl github](https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/issues/1046).

Comment: Check out if your issue is solved, when building from source on the `master` branch, like it was done in this [issue](https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/issues/1046).*